# Rotation of objects from different axes in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

In my game, I have made 4 lines with different colors to form a square but the colored lines are different objects. I want to rotate the lines in a way that the lines will still form a square. Eg:
[image]

But I'm only able to rotate them on the central axis, so, it forms a cross:
[image]

The code for `leftPressed` is:

```
if(leftPressed)
{
black.rotation -= 90;
blue.rotation -= 90;
yellow.rotation -= 90;
red.rotation -= 90;
}
```

So, I need to know how to rotate objects on different axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addChild()` each line into a new parent `DisplayObject` called `square`. Then rotate `square` instead of each of the children, individually. Flash will handle the correct rotation of the children therein.

Do this once:

```
var square:DisplayObject = new Sprite(); //Can't instantiate DisplayObject - it's abstract. So use Sprite.

//you'll need to get references to each of the lines used here (left to you):
square.addChild(black);
square.addChild(blue);
square.addChild(yellow);
square.addChild(red);
```

Do this every update:

```
if (leftPressed)
{
    square.rotation -= 90;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example or anything??

Comment: @uvrichest Example added.

Comment: I did the exact same thing but my character is now dying automatically as it enters the scene

Comment: @uvrichest Well, I've answered your question as it was put. You need to figure out how to make it work with your own code. Ask another, separate question and mark this as accepted. (checkmark beside answer)

Comment: After adding other objects as child of the main one, the objects seem to rotate by making the object an axis.

Comment: @uvrichest Your last comment wasn't too clear. Not sure if you're saying that it works or not! If you're saying that the objects appear in a cross shape as in your second image, that's because they're still sitting at [0,0] - you also need to move them by half their length _outward_: so if each line is 2 units long, you need to move them to [0,1], [0,-1], [1,0] and [-1,0] respectively. This will give you the square you want. Alternatively, `square` can be set up in the library and you can drag the lines where you want them, therein.

Comment: There's a error saying "Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a refernece with static type flash:Display:DisplayObject."